# Specify the consecutive values (zeros) and remove them but only if they are consecutive

Tags: python, list, loops

I have this list of values:

`A = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,6,6,8,8,0,0,2,3,4,5,12,45,-0,-0,-9,-2,3,-0,-2,-2,-2]`

I want to get this list of values for the output :

`A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0,6,6,8,8,2,3,4,5,12,45,-9,-2,3,-0,-2,-2,-2]`

Basically, I want to drop the **consecutive zeros** only, and keep all the other values.

Do you have any idea on how i can do that ? I tried this one but i know there will be in index error :

````
X = []
for j in range(len(A)):
    if A[j] != 0 and A[j+1] != 0:
        X.append(A[j])
    else:
        print('lol')
print(X)```
````

Comment: why does `6,0,6,6` convert to `6,6,0,6`?

Comment: Error from me, it's 6,0,6,6

Comment: you cannot iterate until `range(len(A))` if inside you evaluate `A[j+1]`. You need to change to `range(len(A) - 1)`

Comment: @timgeb i just confused it when typing on the site, thank you

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I tried that but i'm not getting what i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable(G for k,g in groupby(A)
                               if len(G:=list(g))<2 or k!=0))
```

Explanation:

`groupby` will group the consecutive values. For each group, if the length is no more than 1 or the key (=value) is not 0, keep it. Finally `chain` all the groups together and convert to list.

Note that `groupby` returns iterators so I am using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) to perform the conversion.

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 6, 6, 8, 8, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 45, -9, -2, 3, 0, -2, -2, -2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! it's working for me. Hope you have a great day sir !

Answer (score 0):

With `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

X = [x
     for x, [*xs] in groupby(A)
     if x or len(xs) == 1
     for x in xs]
```

Alternatively:

```
X = []
for x, [*xs] in groupby(A):
    if x or len(xs) == 1:
        X += xs
```

Or taking any `x` that's not zero or where the previous and next values are not zero (padding with `1`):

```
X = [x
     for p, x, n in zip([1]+A, A, A[1:]+[1])
     if x or p and n]
```

Comment: Thank you this method is also working. Have a nice day sir !

Comment: @DiamondProx Hmm, you seem to be happy with two of the answers, but didn't upvote or accept any?

Answer (score -1):

if u dont want to import itertools and prefer [list comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html)

```
A = [i for index,i in enumerate(A) if i!=0 or index not in [0,len(A)] and A[index-1]!=i and A[index+1]!=i ]
```

note that this expressions uses the [precedence](https://pythongeeks.org/python-operator-precedence/) of and operator over or operator

[enumerate](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) is used too

Comment: This crashes if there's a zero at the end.

Comment: And if there's a single zero at the start, you remove it.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more simple, easy, and bit lengthy than other answers method to solve your problem

```
A = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,6,6,8,8,0,0,2,3,4,5,12,45,-0,-0,-9,-2,3,-0,-2,-2,-2]
ind=[i for i,j in enumerate(A) if j==0]
C=[(ind[i],ind[i+1]) for i in range(len(ind)-1) if ind[i]+1==ind[i+1]]
D=[i for i1 in C for i in i1]
E=["" if i in D else j for i,j in enumerate(A)]
F=[i for i in E if i!=""]

# TEST
d_output=[1,2,3,4,5,6,0,6,6,8,8,2,3,4,5,12,45,-9,-2,3,-0,-2,-2,-2]
print(F==d_output)
```

> Output: 1 i.e Your desired output

If you want to specify the value, then you can wrap it up in a function as below:

```
def remove_c(list_2,val):
    ind=[i for i,j in enumerate(list_2) if j==val]
    C=[(ind[i],ind[i+1]) for i in range(len(ind)-1) if ind[i]+1==ind[i+1]]
    D=[i for i1 in C for i in i1]
    E=["" if i in D else j for i,j in enumerate(A)]
    return [i for i in E if i!=""]
print(remove_c(A,10))
```

Explantion:

1. I have taken all the indexes of 0 in the list.
2. Checked if the indexes are consecutive or not. If they are, then append them in the list `C` in tuple.
3. And, because the list `C` contains tuple, created a flat list `D` out of list `C`.
4. Replaced the indexes of list `D` with "".
5. Removed "" for the list.
   I have noticed a silly mistake in your code:

```
X = []
for j in range(len(A)): # Mistake here
    if A[j] != 0 and A[j+1] != 0: # if we bypassed the above error we can also get error here
        X.append(A[j])
    else:
        print('lol')
print(X)
```

The problem is when the i is at last index of the list, there would be no other index but you have hard-coded to search for index+1, so it would throw an error.

There are 2 method to solve this:

- Use `try` and `except`.
- Replace `range(len(A)` to `range(len(A)-1)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy , please do specify the bug, i can run it with out error on my system.

Comment: @KellyBundy , for you i have also reverified my answer using different example, it's working fine for me, it would be better if you provide me with the error.

Comment: @KellyBundy , Thanks, that was a valid bug, i have made an edit on my post.

Comment: @KellyBundy , now the output for your example are `[1,2,3]` and `[660,0,6]` respectively.

Comment: @KellyBundy , my bad, i forgot to edit one line.:)

Comment: @KellyBundy , thanks a lot Kelly, you really helped me to fix my code, i hope now it works perfectly.